# How to manually fire the field:error event in ParselyJS

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

In ParsleyJS you can manually add an error to an input by calling the addError method. Like so:

```
$('#myInput').addError("myCustomError", {message : "An error has occurred"});
```

What I'm finding though is that this doesn't trigger the `field:error` event.  I've got a global listener setup for this event.

Is there a way to trigger the `field:error` event with manually added errors?

Comment: `$('#myInput').trigger('field:error')` seems to work.  The only thing is that in my listener I want to use the error message.  I would expect this to be `"An error has occurred"` but it's blank.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle which shows the field:error event getting triggered, but the value returned from `getErrorsMessages` is `[]` rather than `["An error has occurred"]`.  https://jsfiddle.net/garyboyle/16eu7qfh/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$('#myInput').parsley().trigger('field:error')`

Comment: Thanks Marc-André. This answers my question.